# Redux Form Initialises but still keeps it Pristine when I want it to be not Pristine

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have successfully followed the example below:

https://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/initializefromstate/

However there is one difference I would like to make and that is after initialising the form I would like the form to activate the SUBMIT bottom by setting `pristine` to `false` and not keep it as `true`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

Use this method:

```
this.props.initialize(data)
```

Making sure that `enableReinitialize` is not set or set to false:

```
DisplayContactForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'contactform', 
  enableReinitialize: false,

  validate
})(DisplayContactForm);
```